# DrawerLayout not able to resolve to a type

Tags: c#, android, drawerlayout

I have updated the Android support library using Android SDK manager -> install option to rev19.

I am using Visual Studio IDE to build my android application.

I am also referring to the following sample for implementing DrawerLayout but I could not get the DRawerLayout to work in the sample either. [Here is the link](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/DrawerSample) to the sample.

Am I missing out something?

Comment: Please provide detailed description for errors you get?

Comment: I also updated Xamarin.Android to 4.2.2 and also reinstalled the Android Support Library to rev 19. But while deploying the app I am getting the following error:    System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DrawerSample.DrawerSampleActivity' from assembly 'DrawerSample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.